# How do I change a parent theme's function through the child theme?

Tags: functions, child-theme

This is a function loaded by the parent theme. Through the child theme, I want to change this function to say `is_single` instead of `is_singular`. What would be the correct way to achieve this?

```
add_action('wp_head', 'dt_specific_enqueues');
function dt_specific_enqueues() {

    if (is_singular()) {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'comment-reply' );
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parent theme's `functions.php` will load automatically. You don't need to "read" it, and you don't want to "hack" it either manually, which will be overwritten, or programatically, which is very resource intensive.

Your theme is enqueueing the script on the `wp_head` action. You just need to remove that callback and add a slightly modified one. The trick is that your child theme's `functions.php` loads after your parent `functions.php` so you need to get the timing right.

```
function dequeue_dt_specific_enqueues() {
  remove_action('wp_head', 'dt_specific_enqueues');
}
add_action('after_setup_theme', 'dequeue_dt_specific_enqueues');
```

Then add back your own version:

```
function altered_dt_specific_enqueues() {
  if (is_single()) {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'comment-reply' );
  }
}
add_action('wp_head', 'altered_dt_specific_enqueues');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `remove_action` to remove a particular action done by your parent theme (within your child theme, before adding your own action to that hook **[wp_head]**) and then add your own action with `add_action` in your child theme.

**References:**

[Remove Action](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_action)

[Add Action](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_action)